# Unable to cast COM object of type 'FAXCOMEXLib.FaxServerClass'

Tags: vb.net

Hi All,
I have created a Dotnet Application using Dotnet 4.0 Programming language as VB.Net4.0. I have a Windows Service which sends out Fax Document using FaxComexLib Com Component, i have its Inetrop.FaxComexLib.dll, it works great in Windows 7 and Window 2008 Server, i can send out Faxes without any problems.
I have a Legacy Client which Windows XP home with ServicePack3 , i installed my WindowsService there and the Service Works fine other than communicationg with the FaxComexLib Com Component. I tried Several Possible solutions, i copied the the Registry entry({571CED0F-5609-4F40-9176-547E3A72CA7C}) from windows 7 to windows XP, Still no luck

Here is my exception:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'FAXCOMEXLib.FaxServerClass' 
to interface type 'FAXCOMEXLib.IFaxServer2'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{571CED0F-5609-4F40-9176-547E3A72CA7C}' failed due to the following error:
 No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, Boolean& pfNeedsRelease)
   at FAXCOMEXLib.FaxServerClass.Connect(String bstrServerName)

Any Solutions for this would be greatly appeciated.

Thanks In advance
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

It's been a looong time since I used FaxComExLib, but if memory serves, you need to install the Fax printer or something for XP, it is not installed by default.

Comment: I am good with Fax Printer settings and Fax Console Settings, i am able to send out Faxes from FaxConsole Via the Fax Modem. Problem is i am not able to send out documents from my Dotnet application.